# Error: the <column-name> is of time without time zone but expression is of type character varying

Tags: java, postgresql

i am using a postgresql database. I insert the values to the database from a java class. I have declared  the field which is of datatype time without time zone as a String. I am not knowing how to parse and send it to database which matches the data type? How do I do this?

```
public static void User(Form t)
{
String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO DBUSER"
    + "(USER_ID, USERNAME,CREATED_DATE) VALUES"
    + "(?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement ps = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);
ps.setString(1, t.getUserID());
ps.setString(2, t.getuserName());
ps.setString(3, t.getTime());
ps.executeUpdate();
}
```

Error: Error: the CREATED_DATE is of time without time zone but expression is of type character varying
Hint: try to cast the expression

Comment: and you are using plaing SQL or some kind of JPA?

Comment: Show the **exact text** of the query, and the **exact text** of the error, along with the postgresql version please. (Edit question, comment here when done).

Answer (score 4):

Try to add explicit type casting

change
`+ "(?,?,?)";`

to
`+ "(?,?, CAST (? AS time))";`